# Handle events in subviews in MVVM in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mvvm

I am trying to get into MVVM in Swift and I am wondering how to handle events in subviews in MVVM, and how these events can travel up the chain of views/viewmodels. I'm talking about pure Swift for now (no SwiftRx etc.).

**Example**

Say I have a `TableViewController` with a `TableViewModel`. The view model holds an array of objects and creates a `TableCellViewModel` for each one, since each cell represents one of these objects. The `TableViewController` gets the number of rows to display from its model and also the view model for each cell, so it can pass it along to the cell.

We then have a `TableCell` and each cell has a `TableCellViewModel`. The `TableCell` queries its model for things like user-facing strings etc.

Now let's say `TableCell` also has a delete button that delete's that row. I'm wondering how to handle that: Usually, the cell would forward the button press to its view model, but this is not where we need it - we eventually need to know about the button press in either `TableViewController` or `TableViewModel`, so we can remove the row from the table view.

**So the question is:**
How does the button event get from a `TableCell` upwards in the view chain in MVVM?

**Code**

As requested in the comments, code that goes with the example:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var viewModel: TableViewModel = TableViewModel()

    // setup and such

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.viewModel = self.viewModel.cellViewModel(at: indexPath.item)
        return cell
    }

}

class TableViewModel {

    // setup, get data from somewhere, ...

    var count: Int {
        return self.modelObjects.count
    }

    func cellViewModel(at index: Int) -> TableCellViewModel {
        let modelObject = self.modelObjects[index]
        let cellViewModel = TableCellViewModel(modelObject: modelObject)
        return cellViewModel
    }

}

class TableCell {

    var viewModel: TableCellViewModel!

    // setup UI, do what a cell does

    func viewModelChanged() {
        self.titleLabel.text = self.viewModel.title()
    }

    func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Oh, what to do, what to do?
    }

}

class TableCellViewModel {

    private var modelObject: ModelObject

    init(modelObject: ModelObject) {
        self.modelObject = modelObject
    }

    func title() -> String {
        return self.modelObject.title
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting question I've also faced on daily basis. I have bad quality solution, will write it later if you want.

Comment: could you show your tableview datasource methods?

Comment: this is just a super simplistic example, but I've added some code to illustrate the example a bit better

Comment: @BlackWolf I use `cellViewModel` as data storage and preprocessor. All user actions send to `viewController` using a delegation pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableViewModel` is the source of truth, so all global operations should be performed in there. Pressing a button is completely UI operation and viewModel shouldn't handle this in direct way.

So, for now we know two facts:

1. `TableViewModel` should delete the cell from array and then viewController should handle the deletion animation process;
2. Button press shouldn't be handled in child viewModel.

According to this you can achieve it by:

1. Pass button pressed event up to viewController (use callback or delegate pattern);
2. Call `TableViewModel` method to delete specific cell:

   `viewModel.deleteCell(at: indexPath)`
3. Properly handle deletion animation in viewController.

Comment: I've read up a bit more on MVVM, and I think this is the "correct" solution. I thought views were supposed to pass events to the view model, but they're supposed to pass events to the controller. I would still be interested: Should one keep the view model for the cells around, or should we put everything in a single model?

Comment: @BlackWolf my instinct would be you can discard `TableCellViewModel` and simply populate each cells data as it's built, since you have access to that information at that point (`TableViewModel`). I may be wrong however - I wouldn't be on this question if I didn't have gaps in my own knowledge. lol

Comment: Question of my own: @pacification , if I have a generic subclass of UITableView, how would I handle things then? In this example, the viewModel conveniently lives within the tableView, making any calls to it rather simple. However, if using a generic UITableView subclass - does one store a reference to the viewModel in there? Hope I'm making sense... thanks

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use `nextResponder` util nextResponder is VC, and VC responder to delegate (eg:CellEventDelegate) that handle delete data and cell

```
UIResponder *nextResponder = pressedCell.nextResponder;
        while (nextResponder) {
            if ([nextResponder conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CellEventDelegate)]) {
                if ([nextResponder respondsToSelector:@selector(onCatchEvent:)]) {
                    [((id<CellEventDelegate>)nextResponder) onCatchEvent:event];
                }
                break;
            }
            nextResponder = nextResponder.nextResponder;
        }
```

Comment: I've thought about that, and I think technically you can make it work, but I'm more interested how this sort of thing is handled in the MVVM pattern